# touchesBegan doesnt get detected

Tags: iphone

I have a viewcontroller like the following. But the touchsBegan doestnt get detected.
Can anyone plz tell me what is wrong.

```
- (id)init
{

  if (self = [super init])
    self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]] autorelease];    
  return self;  
}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated

{
  overlay = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"overlay.png"]] autorelease];

  [self.view addSubview:overlay]; 

}


- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{     
  // Detect touch anywhere

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    // Where is the point touched

  CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view]; 
  NSLog(@"pointx: %f pointy:%f", point.x, point.y);

  // Was a tab touched, if so, which one...

  if (CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectMake(1, 440, 106, 40), point))

      NSLog(@"tab 1 touched");

    else if (CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectMake(107, 440, 106, 40), point))

      NSLog(@"tab 2 touched");

    else if (CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectMake(214, 440, 106, 40), point))

      NSLog(@"tab 3 touched");

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Touches are only called on `UIView`s. This means you have to subclass `UIView` and put your `touchesBegan:withEvent:` code in this subclass. You're using the code inside an `UIViewController` and this doesn't get any touches itself because it's not an object on screen. A controller is just for the application logic behind a view.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to create a UIView subclass

Comment: Have a look on Apple docs for this. It also seems to me, that you're trying to use a tabbar. You don't check for the position of the touch yourself. Each `UIView` subclass will to that for you. Just read the docs:
http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/navigation/index.html

Comment: Actually the above code is to create a overlay image to a playing movie. That is why i need to check for position instead of a tabbar.

Comment: i m not sure if u can detect touch over the movie thing.. unless u subclass a view and then detect the touch there..

Answer (score 0):

As chriB said touches are detected only on views and as u access it in a controller its not detected.

also FYI, the touches wont be detected on any views you add over the base view.

ie: if u have a view and u add a scroll view or a table view over it, then the touches wont be detected over this added regions. same goes for buttons, textfields etc. Touch is detected  only wen its done exactly on the base view.

Comment: hey i realized jus now, check where you are touching on the screen. i mean hope u are not touching on a button,textfield or a added view.